# How do I do URL encoding of ASCII characters?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, url-encoding

I'm using Ruby to extract a URL of a file to download and download it. The file name has utf8 characters, ex:

```
www.domain.com/.../ÖÇÄÜ360ÓïÒôÖúÀí.txt
```

When trying to download the above URL, it fails. Using `URI::escape` produces a URI that also doesn't work:

```
www.domain.com/.../%C3%96%C3%87%C3%84%C3%9C360%C3%93%C3%AF%C3%92%C3%B4%C3%96%C3%BA%C3%80%C3%AD.txt
```

But if I follow the [URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), it works:

```
www.domain.com/.../%D6%C7%C4%DC360%D3%EF%D2%F4%D6%FA%C0%ED.txt
```

I tried to search for a function in Ruby that does the exact same encoding, but I couldn't find any. Before I try to write a function that implements the table in the link above, I want to ask if anyone know any existing library that does this. And if I decide to do this, what range of characters I should encode, obviously, not everything.

I'm using JRuby 1.6.2 with RUBY_VERSION => "1.8.7"

Comment: The bytes C3 96 are a UTF-8-encoded Ö.  The same character is represented in ASCII as the single byte D6.  So one way to approach the problem is to convert your UTF-8 characters to ASCII, where you can, and then URI::escape.  But that won't help you for Unicode characters that have no ASCII equivalent.

Comment: Have you tried [`CGI.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape)?

Comment: @DavidGorsline: This doesn't work. I end up with '?' for all characters except for '360' and '.txt'. The example above is a real example, do if you have any ideas you can test them on the string'ÖÇÄÜ360ÓïÒôÖúÀí.txt' and let me know how to do it. Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: @muistooshort: CGI.escape gives the same result as URI.escape which is not the encoding I'm looking for. I'm looking for the encoding represented by the table [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: That's http://w3fools.com/ and you should avoid them. That encoding table is using [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) and you shouldn't be using that either, you should be using UTF-8. If you need Latin-1 then you'll have to transcode your UTF-8 to Latin-1 separately.

Comment: @muistooshort it’s worse than that - the table is [Windows 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: I agree, but the 3rd party service I'm dealing with and which I can't change is using that type of encoding. And on the same w3school page, there are two examples, the second one demonstrate the javascript encoding function which result is the same as URI.escape. But if you try the first example which demonstrate how the browser encode URLs before it send it to the server and it uses the same encoding I'm looking for that is represented by the table I keep referring to. When I saw that the browser is URL encoding this in the same way, I started to believe that this is a correct way to do it.

Comment: If you still think I can get to the same results using more than one step conversion, can you provide me with some code example so I can better understand what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @matt: Right, it does look like CP1252, the `‰` line up. And the fools call it ASCII so we have yet another reason to stay away from them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oh, the joys of character encodings!

What’s happening here is as follows. Ruby internally is storing the string you have extracted as a sequence of bytes that is the utf-8 encoding of the name of the file. When you call `URI.escape` on it, those bytes are escaped in `%xy` format, and the resulting string, which now consists solely of bytes in the ASCII range, is used as the url.

The receiving server however, is interpreting those bytes (after unescaping them from `%xy` form) as if they were in a different encoding, in this case [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), and so the resulting filename it comes up with doesn’t match anything it has.

Here’s a demonstration using Ruby 1.9, as it has better support for encodings.

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > f
 => "ÖÇÄÜ360ÓïÒôÖúÀí.txt" 
1.9.3-p194 :004 > f.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
1.9.3-p194 :005 > URI.escape f
 => "%C3%96%C3%87%C3%84%C3%9C360%C3%93%C3%AF%C3%92%C3%B4%C3%96%C3%BA%C3%80%C3%AD.txt" 
1.9.3-p194 :006 > g = f.encode 'iso-8859-1'
 => "\xD6\xC7\xC4\xDC360\xD3\xEF\xD2\xF4\xD6\xFA\xC0\xED.txt" 
1.9.3-p194 :007 > g.encoding
 => #<Encoding:ISO-8859-1> 
1.9.3-p194 :008 > URI.escape g
 => "%D6%C7%C4%DC360%D3%EF%D2%F4%D6%FA%C0%ED.txt"
```

The solution *in this case* is therefore to encode the string as ISO-8859-1 before escaping it. In Ruby 1.9 you do this as above, in earlier versions you can use Iconv (I’m assuming JRuby includes Iconv, I’m actually not that familiar with JRuby):

```
1.8.7 :001 > f
 => "\303\226\303\207\303\204\303\234360\303\223\303\257\303\222\303\264\303\226\303\272\303\200\303\255.txt" 
1.8.7 :005 > g = Iconv.conv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8', f)
 => "\326\307\304\334360\323\357\322\364\326\372\300\355.txt" 
1.8.7 :006 > URI.escape f
 => "%C3%96%C3%87%C3%84%C3%9C360%C3%93%C3%AF%C3%92%C3%B4%C3%96%C3%BA%C3%80%C3%AD.txt" 
1.8.7 :007 > URI.escape g
 => "%D6%C7%C4%DC360%D3%EF%D2%F4%D6%FA%C0%ED.txt"
```

Note that in general you can’t depend on the server using any particular encoding. It *should* be using utf-8, but obviously isn’t in this case.

Comment: This was very helpful didn't have a clue that I needed to URI.escape after encoding.